# I am inserting scraped data into mysql but raises the following error

Tags: mysql, selenium, web-scraping

I create a python webscraping script with selenium to scrape profiles from researchgate   website and want to store the results in mysql database.
but i got this error and tried very much for a  month but can't find solution to this error.
This is the code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 
import time
import sys
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="your username",
  password="your password",
  db='your database'
)

cur = mydb.cursor()


#create table
cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Data""")

cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Data
               (Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                Name varchar(20),
                Institution VARCHAR(255),
                Department varchar(255),
                Citations INTEGER,
                Recommendation INTEGER, 
                Total_Reads INTEGER, 
                Total_research_interest DECIMAL(7,1), 
                Research_items INTEGER,
                Projects INTEGER, 
                Questions  INTEGER,
                Answers INTEGER, 
                scores int,
                Followers INTEGER,
                Followings INTEGER
               )''')



login_url = 'https://www.researchgate.net/login'
base_url = "https://www.researchgate.net/institution/Islamia_College_Peshawar/department/Department_of_Computer_Science/members"
chrome_driver_path = '/home/danish-khan/scrapers/researchgate/chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
  executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options
)

# default login credential and search query
username = 'your username'
password = 'your password'
search_query = "Islamia college Peshawar"
results = []

with webdriver as driver:
    # Set timeout time 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # retrive url in headless browser
    driver.get(login_url)
    
    driver.find_element_by_id("input-login").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("input-password").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("nova-c-button__label").find_element(By.XPATH, "./..").click()
    time.sleep(5)

    driver.get(base_url)

    time.sleep(10)
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    #names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.display-name')
    name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="list people-list-m"]/li//a[@class="display-name"]')
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    print(len(name))
    name_selector = '.nova-e-text--color-grey-900'
    #selector = '.display-name'
    selector = '//ul[@class="list people-list-m"]/li//a[@class="display-name"]'
    #for i in range(0,1):
    for i in range(0,len(name)):
             #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        
            #time.sleep(5)
            links = WebDriverWait(driver, 70).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, selector))
              )
                    
             
            links[i].click()
#            name_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
#            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, name_selector))
#            )
            time.sleep(5)
            Name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-e-text--color-grey-900').text
            try:
              Institution = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-v-institution-item__title .nova-e-link--theme-bare').text
            except:
              Institution = ''
              
            try:    
              Department = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-v-institution-item__info-section-list-item .nova-e-link--theme-bare').text
            except:
              Department = ''
            
            try:   
              Citations = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(2) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
              Citations = int(Citations.replace(",", ""))
            except:
              Citations = '' 
                 
            try:     
              Recommendation =   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(3) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
            except:
              Recommendation = ''  
            
            try:  
              Total_Reads = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(4) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text                      
              Total_Reads = int(Total_Reads.replace(",", ""))
            except:
              Total_Reads = '' 
            
            try:
              Total_research_interest =   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(1) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text           
              Total_research_interest = (Total_research_interest.replace(",", ""))
            except:
              Total_research_interest = ''
            
            try:
              Research_items = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(1) .nova-e-text--color-inherit').text
              Research_items = Research_items
            except:
              Research_items = ''
            
            try:
              Projects = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(2) .nova-e-text--color-inherit').text
              Projects = Projects
            except:
              Projects = ''
       
            try:   
              Questions = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(3) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
              Questions = Questions
            except:
              Questions = ''
            
            try:
              Answers = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(4) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
              Answers = Answers  
            except:
              Answers = ''
            
            
            try:
                scores = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.profile-header-details-meta-items .nova-e-list__item:nth-child(1)').text
                
                scores = scores
            except: 
                scores = 0
                    
            #Scores = Scores[0]
            
            try:                             
              Followings = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Following')]").text.strip('Following').strip('( )')
    
            except:
              Followings = 0
              print('No  Followers')  
            
            
            
            
            try:                             
              Followers = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Followers')]").text.strip('Followers').strip('( )')
    
            except:
              Followers = 0
              print('No  Followers')  
            
            
         
            print(scores) 
            print(Citations)
            print(Recommendation)
            print(Total_Reads)
            print(Total_research_interest)
            print()  
           
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.back()
            
            time.sleep(5)
            #driver.close()   
        
             
        

            time.sleep(10)

            cur.execute('INSERT INTO Data(Name,Institution,Department,Citations, Recommendation, Total_Reads , Total_research_interest , Research_items , Projects, Questions , Answers , scores , Followers, Followings) VALUES("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s", "%s" )' % (Name,Institution,Department,Citations, Recommendation, Total_Reads , Total_research_interest , Research_items , Projects, Questions , Answers , scores , Followers, Followings ) )
            #driver.close()
            mydb.commit()
            print('complete.')


mydb.close()
time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```

Below is the output error which i tried but can't understand why this error occurs.

```
20
17.92
301
28
5406
230.7

complete.
11.54
79
66
3356
92.1

complete.

5
2
392
9.9

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 507, in cmd_query
    self._cmysql.query(query,
_mysql_connector.MySQLInterfaceError: Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'scores' at row 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resgt5.py", line 208, in <module>
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO Data(Name,Institution,Department,Citations, Recommendation, Total_Reads , Total_research_interest , Research_items , Projects, Questions , Answers , scores , Followers, Followings) VALUES("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s", "%s" )' % (Name,Institution,Department,Citations, Recommendation, Total_Reads , Total_research_interest , Research_items , Projects, Questions , Answers , scores , Followers, Followings ) )
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor_cext.py", line 274, in execute
    result = self._cnx.cmd_query(stmt, raw=self._raw,
  File "/home/danish-khan/scrapers/scrpers/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection_cext.py", line 511, in cmd_query
    raise errors.get_mysql_exception(exc.errno, msg=exc.msg,
mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'scores' at row 1
```

Comment: Can you share more details? The given code uses a **single** column named `scores`, while the error message uses that same table with **four** columns

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you are assigning to `scores`, in `scores = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(...).text` is not an `integer` - i.e. the element's value text is not an integer. Print it out & you will see what it actually it

MySQL would convert it automatically from text to int, so if the value you have in `scores` was an `int`, your code would have worked.

Personally, if its meant to be an integer, I would use `VALUES(%d)' % (scores)`, which could require you convert `scores` into an `integer` before hand, so `scores = int(driver.find_element_by_css_selector...`

Your `drop table` also doesn't seem to be working as it seems to think there is already a table called `DATA` `->` `DATA(Name,recommendation,treads,scores )`

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
import time
import sys
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="danish-khan",
  password="12345",
  db='reseachgate_profiles'
)

cur = mydb.cursor()


#create table
cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Data""")

cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Data
               (Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                Name varchar(20),
                Institution VARCHAR(255),
                Department varchar(255),
                Citations INTEGER,
                Recommendation INTEGER, 
                Total_Reads INTEGER, 
                Total_research_interest DECIMAL(7,1), 
                Research_items INTEGER,
                Projects INTEGER, 
                Questions  INTEGER,
                Answers INTEGER, 
                scores int,
                Followers INTEGER,
                Followings INTEGER
               )''')



login_url = 'https://www.researchgate.net/login'
base_url = "https://www.researchgate.net/institution/Islamia_College_Peshawar/department/Department_of_Computer_Science/members"
chrome_driver_path = '/home/danish-khan/scrapers/researchgate/chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
  executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options
)

# default login credential and search query
username = 'danishkhankd237@gmail.com'
password = 'danish3.16khan'
search_query = "Islamia college Peshawar"
results = []

with webdriver as driver:
    # Set timeout time 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

    # retrive url in headless browser
    driver.get(login_url)
    
    driver.find_element_by_id("input-login").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("input-password").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("nova-c-button__label").find_element(By.XPATH, "./..").click()
    time.sleep(5)

    driver.get(base_url)

    time.sleep(10)
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    #names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.display-name')
    name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="list people-list-m"]/li//a[@class="display-name"]')
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    print(len(name))
    name_selector = '.nova-e-text--color-grey-900'
    #selector = '.display-name'
    selector = '//ul[@class="list people-list-m"]/li//a[@class="display-name"]'
    #for i in range(0,1):
    for i in range(1,len(name)):
             #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
        
            #time.sleep(5)
            links = WebDriverWait(driver, 70).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, selector))
              )
                    
             
            links[i].click()
#            name_e = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
#            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, name_selector))
#            )
            time.sleep(5)
            Name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-e-text--size-xl.nova-e-text--color-grey-900').text
            try:
              Institution = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-v-institution-item__title .nova-e-link--theme-bare').text
            except:
              Institution = 'NA'
              
            try:    
              Department = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-v-institution-item__info-section-list-item .nova-e-link--theme-bare').text
            except:
              Department = 'NA'
            
            try:   
              Citations = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(2) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
            except:
              Citations = ''  
                 
            try:     
              Recommendation =   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(3) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
            except:
              Recommendation = ''  
            
            try:  
              Total_Reads = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(4) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text                      
              Total_Reads = int(Total_Reads.replace(",", ""))
            except:
              Total_Reads = '' 
            
            try:
              Total_research_interest =   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(1) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text,           
              Total_research_interest = Total_research_interest[0]
            except:
              Total_research_interest = ''
            
            try:
              Research_items = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(1) .nova-e-text--color-inherit').text,
              Research_items = Research_items[0]
            except:
              Research_items = ''
            
            try:
              Projects = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(2) .nova-e-text--color-inherit').text
              Projects = Projects[0]
            except:
              Projects = ''
       
            try:   
              Questions = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(3) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text,
              Questions = Questions[0]
            except:
              Questions = ''
            
            try:
              Answers = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(4) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text,
              Answers = Answers[0]   
            except:
              Answers = ''
            
            
            try:
              scores = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.profile-header-details-meta-items .nova-e-list__item:nth-child(1)').text
            except:
               scores = 0
                    
            #Scores = Scores[0]
              
            try:                             
              Followers = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="nova-o-stack nova-o-stack--gutter-xxl nova-o-stack--spacing-xxs nova-o-stack--show-divider"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/b').text[11:13]
            
            except:
              followers = ''
              print('No  Followers')  
            
            Followings = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="nova-e-text nova-e-text--size-m nova-e-text--family-sans-serif nova-e-text--spacing-none nova-e-text--color-inherit"]/b').text[11:13]
            ''' 
            try:
               Followers = Followers
          
            except: 
               Followers = ''
            '''
            try:
               Followings = Followings
          
            except: 
               Followings = 'NA'
            
            print(scores) 
           
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.back()
            
            time.sleep(5)
            #driver.close()   
        
             
        

            time.sleep(10)

            cur.execute('INSERT INTO Data(Name,Institution,Department,Citations, Recommendation, Total_Reads , Total_research_interest , Research_items , Projects, Questions , Answers , scores , Followers, Followings) VALUES("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s", "%s" )' % (Name,Institution,Department,Citations, Recommendation, Total_Reads , Total_research_interest , Research_items , Projects, Questions , Answers , scores , Followers, Followings ) )
            #driver.close()
            mydb.commit()
            print('complete.')


mydb.close()
time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```